# How to change request http method by using Charles proxy?

Tags: http, http-proxy, charles-proxy

I'm using Charles Proxy for http debugging.

For switching http method GET to POST, I tried to use 'Tool > Rewrite' menu.
But I couldn't find any way on Rewrite menu.

How to switch http method (GET to POST) by using Charles Proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to edit a single response, you should just right click on the item and go to Edit.  There, you can change the "scheme" from GET to POST.

Comment: I don't see the verb PATCH do you know where to find it in Charles?